# How can I make these "if" statements more DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I'm trying to layout some partials as shown below:

```
if controller == home
   render partail 0
else
   render partial 1
end

render partial 2

render partial 3

if controller == home
   render partail 4
end

render partial 5
```

I've repeated the `if controller == home` part three times. Is there any way to make the code follow the "DRY" approach?

Comment: I only see your `if controller` test twice. And, I think you'll have a hard time reducing the code. DRY is a great concept but it is a guiding principle, it isn't a law. Sometimes we have to repeat something because the logic forces it. Just be aware of the need to reduce your code by avoiding repetition, and try to do it.

Comment: You can change the first block like this

    controller == home ? render partail 0 : render partial 1

Comment: @QuaziMarufurRahman Tenary operators doesn't help here, you still have to repeat the controller == home part, it's just a shorter form. Thanks tho.

Comment: @theTinMan yh it has one more just after the partial 5, i see what you mean.

Comment: If there is a trailing `if`, it was missing from your sample code.

Comment: Oh my bad, there should be one there haha. To make matters worse it's in my layout/application.

Comment: I can see maybe building a collection of partials to render and then doing each on it, but I can't see why I'd bother unless I was doing something similar a lot!

Comment: Really smart people on here lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an array:

```
partials = (controller == home) ? [0,2,3,4,5] : [1,2,3,5]

partials.each { |p| render partial p }
```

Comment: Your array partials looks like a ternary statement. Correct me if I am wrong. Looks like a nice short and effective way of doing this

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping `controller == home` inside parenthesis to help visually delimit, and call out the logic test. It helps readability.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I might do it. It's not any more DRY, but it reads better, IMO:

```
flag = controller == home

render flag ? :partial0 : :partial1
render :partial2
render :partial3
render :partial4 if flag
render :partial5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array and since the partials are ordered, sort it, then render:

```
partials = [2,3,5];                     # 2,3,5 are going to be rendered regardless of controller

case controller
when home
   partials.push(0,4);                  # if it's home use 0 and 4
else
   partials.push(1);                    # if not home use 1
end

partials.sort.each { |p| render partial p }  # sort and render in order
```

Note: there is more code in this example, but it is more flexible if you expect to use other conditionals in addition to `home`.  I often find the more robust I make my code up front, it saves me more time in the long run; though, I admit this is less readable as compared to [FMc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55857/fmc)'s answer

Comment: Turning code into a one-liner isn't always desirable or a good thing, especially when using a complex ternary statement. It might be more concise, but that can result in being harder to understand and maintain. I'd recommend keeping the original form. The ternary statement used by @Denis in his answer is easier to understand and would be a better method.

Comment: You could make it a one liner, or use ternary, but the benefit of not using a ternary is to easily enable more conditions and save readability.  For that reason, I changed the `if` to a switch statement.